# Can't set Violin plot to have multiple colours

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to set different colours to violin plots in R. I have been following several tutorials and I can successfully set to one colour but can't set to multiple.

I have been using this code

```
pndviT <-   ggplot(df, aes(x=Class_2, ndvi_mean))+
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE)+
  labs(x="Class", y="NDVI Mean")+stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, mult=1, geom="pointrange", color="black")+
scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#fc9272","#016450","#3690c0", "black"  ))
 pndviT
```

Does anyone see any issues with the script? I can't figure out why it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Erioderma. Map a variable in your data frame (`df`) to the color aesthetic by adding `color = <var>` to the `aes()`.

Comment: Thanks, could you show me an example?